# LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY Issue

Tags: mysql, join

Not written MySQL for a very long time and I can't get my head around why this is not working! I have written the following to hopefully allow me to see crop yield per year.

I have two tables, one states how many plants of said variety with the following fields this is called "growseason":

- id
- username
- variety
- datestamp
- plants

my other table has entries when a user adds a harvest to the database, this is called "harvest" with the following fields:

- id
- datestamp
- username
- variety
- picked
- weight

I am trying to create a table that shows year on year crop per plant, this will give me an indication if the crop is better or worse than the previous year.

```
SELECT g.Variety, 

ROUND(SUM(IF(YEAR(h.datestamp)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE),h.picked,0)) /
IF(YEAR(g.datestamp)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE),g.plants,0),0) As FruitPerPlantThisYear, 

ROUND(SUM(IF(YEAR(h.datestamp)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1,h.picked,0)) /
IF(YEAR(g.datestamp)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)-1,g.plants,0),0) As FruitPerPlantLastYear

FROM harvest h
LEFT JOIN growseason g ON h.variety = g.variety AND YEAR(h.datestamp) = YEAR(g.datestamp) AND h.username = g.username
WHERE g.username = 'Palendrone' AND picked <> '0' 
GROUP BY variety, g.datestamp
```

Expected output:

```
Variety | FruitPerPlantThisYear | FruitPerPlantLastYear
-------------------------------------------------------
Var1    |           34          |           31

Var2    |           112         |           123

Var3    |           67          |           41
```

Actual output:

```
Variety | FruitPerPlantThisYear | FruitPerPlantLastYear
-------------------------------------------------------
Var1    |           34          |            

Var2    |                       |           123

Var3    |                       |           41
```

I understand the g.datestamp in my groupby duplicates the variety names but if I don't add that I am only getting a single instance this year or last year). Having spent hours trying to solve this I am now all out of ideas.

I give in and accept help please! Also not sure how I can structure this any better...

Comment: Hi! Try reformatting your code to make it easier to read. The more readable your question is, the faster they answer it!

Comment: Try to rephrase your question with sample data.  Off the top of my head, those conditions in the `WHERE` clause might belong in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Expected output with no input. A few of my favourite things. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Probably very simple and I am stumped, I used to do data analysis for a living with a little MySQL at a very basic level. My understanding of it is limited and I was merely trying to solve a fun problem as I store some of my data in MySQL. I will attempt to restructure my problem but feel stating "a simple SQL query" a little rude. What is simple to one person could be a challenge for another.

Comment: There isn't g.datestamp in growseason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for conditional aggregation and I don't know where you get g.datestamp from or g.plants since they ain't in your table definition.

```
SELECT g.Variety, 
sum(case when YEAR(h.datestamp)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) then h.picked else 0 end) /
sum(case when YEAR(g.datestamp)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) then g.plants else 0 end) as fruitPerPlantThisYear, 

sum(case when YEAR(h.datestamp)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) -1 then h.picked else 0 end) /
sum(case when YEAR(g.datestamp)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) -1 then g.plants else 0 end) as fruitPerPlantThislastYear 

FROM harvest h
LEFT JOIN growseason g ON h.variety = g.variety AND h.username = g.username
WHERE g.username = 'Palendrone' AND picked <> '0' 
GROUP BY g.variety
```

Comment: Updated lists, thank you for your thoughts, have tried this and still not giving me the numbers I'd expect, I'll post better comments once I've collated all my thoughts to enable better help. Thanks again :0)

Comment: If you would like to add sample data and expected results to your question as text or to sqlfiddle then I would be happy to look again.